# Why is my angular app not running properly in internet explorer? (ng-app="id" and elements included)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a simple app to run in internet explorer.

The problem seem to be associated with the scope.

- I have added document.createElement for all my directives. They show
  up in the DOM with their content. The app seems to initialize:

  ```
  angular.module('signupForm', []).run(function(){alert('init');})
  ```

  triggers an alert
- I have added `id="ng-app"`to my app-root node.
- I have added `xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"` but I don't have any other custom name-spaces.

I believe the problem is associated with the scope, because an element with `ng-show="posted"` shows if `posted != true`. and the variables in the template are represented as curlybrackets `{{label}}` rather than what they are suppose to be.

I don't get any errors or messages, I try to figure out how to move forward.

http://signup.jungrelations.com/tigeraw14/ is the url for the app

plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/o2F8ZfhSxTlojQXYqw2B

Comment: Your link is broken. Either way you should include your code inside the question itself and preferably paste a plunker link.

Comment: UPdated link, i'll make a plunker momentarily

Comment: I tried to create a plunkr, but I can't get it running for some reason...